# How to make a slider with a picture flip?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, animation

I have to implement a slider of pictures that are flipped. I made a slider, but the pictures just change, and the flip works separately. How should I change my code to make it work correctly

My HTML
I have a card with a picture on one side and a picture on the back

```
            <div className={s.slider}>
                <div className={s.sliderImg} key={activeIndex}>
                    <div className={s.front}>{img[activeIndex]}</div>
                    <div className={s.back}>{img[nextImgIndex]}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

My CSS
I can flip my card but it doesn't work right

```
.slider {
    position: absolute;
    top: 348px;
    left: 776px;
    width: 395px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    perspective: 1000;
}
 
.sliderImg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.slider:hover .sliderImg {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.sliderImg img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.front, .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.front {
    z-index: 2;
}
 
.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

My JS
Pictures change by timer

```
    const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState<number>(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            setActiveIndex((current) => {
                const res = current === img.length - 1 ? 0 : current + 1
                return res
            })
        }, 5000)
        return () => clearInterval(interval)
    }, [])

    const nextImgIndex = activeIndex === img.length - 1 ? 0 : activeIndex + 1
```

Comment: Please send the full code in code-sandbox, so we can easily review and help you out.

Comment: please provide in sandbox